# Skip refreshing dependencies in gradle

Tags: gradle

**Short version of question:**
Is there a way of telling gradle not to resolve dependencies? I know I can skip single task with -x switch but resolving dependencies isn't performed though some task I guess, to I don't know how to do it.

**Long version:**
Right now I can run tests from gradle with simple 'gradle test' which performs gathering dependencies, building and running tests..
But I'd also like to run tests using gradle on some other machine which can't download dependencies from maven. I thought that I could just perform some packaging which would download all dependencies to some lib folder, and I could expand tests classpath (in that task) to this folder. The problem is, that gradle still tries to contact maven when I run 'gradle myTests'. Is there a way of preventing resolving dependencies for this single task?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tell gradle to bypass dependency checks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447544/tell-gradle-to-bypass-dependency-checks)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's the `--offline` flag. Alternatively, you can declare a `flatDir` rather than a `maven` repository whenever the build should be run with "local" dependencies.

Comment: Man you are quick! :) Is it correct if I have defined some maven repositories, and then single flatDir (which will be filled with dependencies downloaded from maven with some task), and if I run some common task, it would look for dependencies in maven repositories first, and if I run it with offline flag, it would use the dependencies form my flatDir?

Comment: Might work but I'm not sure. Alternatively you could conditionally define either a `maven` or a `flatDir` repo, e.g. based on whether some system property (or even `--offline`) is set.

Comment: This solution has one disadvantage - I have to have multiple versions of jars in my flatDir. I understand the reason (dependency resolution and proper version picking is done after gathering all dependencies), but is there some way around this? I'd really like to switch off dependency resolution and just tell gradle what's the classpath for my task.

Answer (score 0):

For my use case, my internet is restricted so I would setup dependencies while I can still have full access. And when I'm restricted, go to `Preferences`, search for `Gradle`, and check "Offline work".

Of course I'll have to turn it back on whenever new dependencies are added.