# Tell gradle to bypass dependency checks

Tags: gradle

I am at a clients site, behind a firewall.  Im trying to compile but gradle keeps trying to check my dependencies.  The corporate firewall explicitly blocks maven downloads so my build is failing.  Now I have compiled before, so the dependencies do already exist in my [user]/.gradle folder, but its been more than 24 hours so gradle is trying to do its daily "lets check the repo and make sure nothing changed stuff."

Is there a command switch or anything that im just simply not seeing here to tell gradle to bypass this version check and simply compile the code?  I would even be happy with a command switch that says I don't care if dependency resolution failed, compile anyways.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Skip refreshing dependencies in gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261512/skip-refreshing-dependencies-in-gradle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `--offline` command line switch.

Comment: Just in case you are a bit lost like me : the --offline parameter is added at the end of a gradle command like : gradlew myCustomTask --offline

Answer (score 0):

You still have to get it to compile once to grab the dependencies online, so --offline only works once you have compiled successfully one time.

The only way I was able to get this to work was to tether my phone to my machine and connect to my cellular service for internet instead. That way, I bypassed my company's proxy and firewall and was able to download the dependencies once.

After that, I was able to then compile when connected to the corporate network instead. Just don't clean your project or else you'll be back where you are right now.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question because I wanted to short-circuit the Maven dependency checks in a git pre-commit hook that runs `gradle check` for better performance.  I ended up doing:

```
if ! ( gradle --offline check || gradle check ); then
  exit 1
fi
```

which tries once with `--offline`, and then tries again without `--offline` if the first try fails.