# Execute gradle task while ignoring dependency resolution step completely

Tags: gradle

I'm new to gradle.

Is it somehow possible to skip the dependency resolution step completely?

I would like to execute a commandLine task during a multi machine build pipeline on a machine with no access to the repo. The task in question does not need the dependencies. It does not depend on other tasks because they are already executed earlier in the pipeline on another machine (the workspace is cloned from machine to machine).

Comment: What happens when you just run this task on the machine without access to repo?

Comment: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':<sub-project-name>:compile'.  and searched in following locations (paths to a network shared ivy repo)

Comment: one of the tasks needs configurations.compile , but it is not the task I'm running, however since that is also a command line task (without the << , I guess gradle tries to find the dependencies)

Comment: There should be a possibility of running gradle with `--offline`. Have You tried?

Comment: I guess I should also mention that that task is run on multiple machines (its a javafx packaging task using javapackager command line), it works on another machine which does have access

Comment: I have tried with --offline, it seems it has no effect. I'm not sure that it would help even if it worked, because to my knowledge it would then need the cache and with currect gradle version it seems to be impossible to cache a network shared ivy repo. (and I would not have the cache anyway since no access).

Comment: Yes, you might be right.

Comment: It is possible, that because the network share is currently considered "local" it is ignored by --offline. I guess as a workaround I have to use some flatDir based solution. Most of the dependencies should be in the workspace at that point in build (since they are packaged anyway), but it's possible that some dependencies are not (obfuscation/jar merging), but I guess I can make a secondary flatDir to keep gradle happy..

Comment: Have you seen this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261512/skip-refreshing-dependencies-in-gradle ?

Comment: Yes. I guess it's the only way. I dont need any dependencies at that point anymore, so it's a pity to do that just in order to execute a task which does not need the dependencies.